# use random function in SQL for one particular column only

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two questions:

1. Is there any possible way to use `dbms_random.random` OR `dbms_random.value`  in Oracle by specifying for one column only?
2. If the above is possible, can i limit the randomly generated value of occurrences maximum 5 times, for example?

I am using Oracle 11g :) Thank you.

`free` Table:

```
freeID | lecturerID  | availableID   
  1         1004           10
  2         1004           11
  3         1004           12
  4         1004           13
  5         1005           11
  6         1005           12
  7         1005           13
  8         1005           14
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.FreeID, e1.lecturerID, e1.AVAILABLEID,
                e2.FREEID, e2.LECTURERID, e2.AVAILABLEID, 
                s.studentID, s.studentName, s.lecturerID
FROM       free e1 
INNER JOIN free e2 
        ON e1.availableID = e2.availableID
JOIN       student s
        ON s.lecturerID = e1.LECTURERID
       AND e1.lecturerID='1004'
       AND e2.lecturerID='1005'
       AND e1.AVAILABLEID = e2.availableid
```

Based on above query, I `INNER JOIN` `free` table with `availableID` to look for `lecturerID` with the same `availableID`.

Then, I `JOIN` again with `student` table with `lecturerID`

Expected outcome:

```
   freeID | e1.lecturerID  | e1.availableID  | e1.availableID  | e2.lecturerID
      1         1004           13                    13              1005
      2         1004           11                    11              1005
      3         1004           12                    12              1005
      4         1004           13                    13              1005
```

I  want the `availableID` column to randomly chose among them as long as they both have same value, each lecturer has the same `availableID` and does not exceed 5 time occurrences. If it exceeds, it will move to the next value.

Comment: What do you mean by one column only? Can you substantiate with an example schema and values?

Comment: It's a random number generator.  They both generate a single random value.  I'm confused by what you mean "for one column only" and "maximum 5 times".  You would generate 5 random numbers if you wanted 5 numbers.

Comment: Those functions return individual values, They don't generate rows of data, they get standalone numbers or strings. Not sure what you've been reading but it must have been doing something more complicated. You can use the output of either function to set a single column value. You'll need to explain more about what you're trying to update and how - if you already have an update statement you want to modify, for example.

Comment: You're talking about generating random values and then you're not utilizing random numbers anywhere in the following example data and query.  Does this question actually relate to random value generation or are you just looking to produce the outcome at the bottom?

Comment: Your data seems to be inconsistent - why are all the free IDs the same? should the 1002 lecturer IDs be 1005? - and you haven't shown the student table or what effect that has on the expected result. What are actually trying to achieve, in plain English not SQL terms?

Comment: @MikeS since you mentioned, it is for generating number, is there any possible way to allow the column to randomly join with another column as long as both ID is similar?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, I am sorry it was writing mistakes. I mean, I want the `availableID` to randomly choose the `lecturerID` as long as both `availableID` is same and it will use the next ID if it has reach 5 occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a window function to assign a row number, in random order, to each join within the same *lecturerID*, and then add the condition that only the 5 first should be taken:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT      e1.FreeID,
                    e1.lecturerID,
                    e1.availableID,
                    e2.lecturerID AS lectureID2,
                    s.studentID,
                    s.studentName,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e1.lecturerID 
                                       ORDER BY dbms_random.random) AS rn
        FROM        free e1 
        INNER JOIN  free e2 
                ON  e1.availableID = e2.availableID
        INNER JOIN  student s
                ON  s.lecturerID = e1.lecturerID
        WHERE       e1.lecturerID = '1004'
               AND  e2.lecturerID = '1005'
        )
WHERE rn <= 5
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time :). I tried but it says `FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: Because there is a comma missing after `AS lectureID2`.

Comment: Thank you @trincot . It is working well so far. I am still studying the query. Thank you again :)

Comment: Thanks, @ThorstenKettner, for mentioning the missing comma.

Comment: @trincot I have a question, does this query works well in large database?

Comment: It will have some performance impact. Certainly, if you have many records that could match (many more than 5 per lecturerID). This is because Oracle will have to generate random numbers for many rows that eventually are not selected, because they are not among the first 5. If indeed this is your case, and you have many more than 5 matches in general, you could look at the `sample` keyword in Oracle. But it works a bit differently, and may not suit your needs.

Comment: I tried to change the value of `rn` to 10, but I am still getting 5 rows. Why is that? @trincot

Comment: Maybe you only have 5 different *availableID* values for the same *lecturerID*? The query will never return more than you have available.

Comment: I think the alternative will be I need to iterate the query? Haha @trincot

Comment: If you really need more records in the result set than you have, then you must generate duplicates. I am not sure how that would be useful though. But you could cross join with another small table having like 5 records. This will multiply the number of records by 5. The row number will then count higher because of that.

Comment: @trincot how can i change this query if I only want the `lectureID2` availableID only? I dont want to match these two values anymore